# discord.py certain people execute command

Tags: python, discord.py

So im trying to make a logout command where only me and one other person can close the bot,

```py
trusted = {id, id}
    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.id  in trusted:       
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Closing Bot")
            await self.bot.close()
        else:
            await ctx.send("Only (me) and (my friend) can execute this")
```

For some reason whenever I try this it doesn't realize that I'm in trusted and doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `intents.members` enabled? If not:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable  them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=primer)

Comment: I have intents=discord.intents.all() and have intents enabled, didnt seem to fix it tho

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permissions#checks) if the user id is in the list. If the author is not there then it will just skip him you can use a error_handler to send the error.

```py
def me_and_friends(ctx):
    trusted = [id, id]
    return ctx.author.id in trusted
```

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.check(me_and_friends)
async def test(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send('This is either me or a friend')
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it seems to raise a Check failure